# Represent the following sentences in FOL:

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Why the FOL for this sentence "The best score in Greek is always higher than the best score in French" is "∀ s ∃ x ∀y Score(x,G, s) > Score(y,F, s)."
I need an explanation about ∃ x and ∀ s?

Comment: ∃ x this symbol means it exists x        ;

∀ s  means for all s   What do you mean by score ?

Comment: why we put this symbol ∃ x while the sentences say "always"? I think we should put ∀x not ∃ x .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a logic question which doesn't involve programming in any essential way.

Comment: duplode sorry for that and I got the answer

Answer (score 1):

∀s ∃x ∀y Score(x,G,s) > Score(y,F,s) is indicating that:

for all scores in Greek (∀s Score(x,G,s)), there exists an score in Greek (∃x Score(x,G,s)) that is higher than all scores in French (∀s ∀y Score(y,F,s)).

According to the scope of the quantifiers, you can reorder the sentence to make it more clear:

∀s [∃x  Score(x,G,s) > ∀y Score(y,F,s)]

The reason for using ∃x instead of ∀x, is that we are saying **"the best score in Greek"** which refers to one of the scores in Greek that is the highest. If we write

∀s ∀x ∀y Score(x,G,s) > Score(y,F,s)

it would mean that "all scores in Greek are higher than all the scores in French" which means even the lowest score in Greek is higher than all the scores in French.

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation and I appreciate it.